# Function passed through props shown non-defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got three components `Topicscreen`, `Listview`, `Listrow`. I am passing the function `renderrow`, and two other properties defined in my 
`Topicscreen` to `Listview`.

Now when i call `func` in `Listview`, the props are passed to `Listrow` as defined in `renderrow` function, but the `onRowclick` function which is being passed to `Listrow` is `undefined` when i checked it in `Listrow`.

How to solve this error and pass `onRowclick` as a function to `Listrow`?

**Topicscreen.js**

```
class Topicscreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onRowClick = this.onRowClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(topicaction.Fetchtopics());
  }

  renderLoading() {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  renderrow(rowid, topic) {
    //const selected = this.props.checkselection[rowid]
    const selected = "";
    return (
      <Listrow selected={selected} clicking={this.onRowClick} rowid={rowid}>
        <h3>{topic.title}</h3>
        <p>{topic.description}</p>
      </Listrow>
    );
  }

  onRowClick(rowid) {
    this.props.dispatch(topicaction.selectedchoice(rowid));
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.topicsByurl) return this.renderLoading();
    return (
      <div className="TopicsScreen">
        Hi I am topic screen
        <h1>Choose any three of the below topics</h1>
        <Listview
          rowid={this.props.topicsurlArray}
          row={this.props.topicsByurl}
          func={this.renderrow}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Listview.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

export default class Listview extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
  }

  show(rowid) {
    return this.props.func(rowid, _.get(this.props.row, rowid));
  }

  render() {
    console.log("props in listview", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{_.map(this.props.rowid, this.show)}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Listrow.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Listrow extends Component {
  clicking() {
    this.props.clicking(this.props.rowid);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("list row called");
    console.log("listrow props", this.props);
    const background = this.props.selected ? "#c0f0ff" : "#fff";
    return (
      <div style={{ background }} onClick={this.clicking.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your three components in their entirety? It's difficult to say what might be wrong with the code that is currently in your question.

Comment: @Tholle added the code of all components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to bind your `renderrow` method in the `Topicscreen` constructor, or `this.onRowClick` inside of `renderrow` will not be what you expect.

```
class Topicscreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onRowClick = this.onRowClick.bind(this);
    this.renderrow = this.renderrow.bind(this);
  }

  // ...
}
```